# What is the difference between <ObjectElement> and <d:ObjectElement> in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I add Object Elements to a XAML file Visual Studio's autocomplete offers me always two choices.

For Example, I can pick between `StackLayout` or `StackLayout (d)`

What is the difference between these two choices and when do I use what?

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful , remember to mark that when you have time :-) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jason said, they're almost the same, but the `d:` is related to the xamarin forms xaml previewer, if you use the designer you can display mockup data through the designer in design time.

You can safely delete from your xaml if you don't use it.

For further info: [Use Design Time Data with the XAML Previewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/design-time-data)

Answer (score 1):

one is in the default namespace, and one is in the namespace mapped to "d" - but odds are they are actually the same